# how to configure imagick on xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, php

I just install Xubuntu 18.04 for my xampp development machine.
I have download and install xampp 7.2.5-0 and there is no error on the install and I can see the default xampp web page on localhost.

It seems that the xubuntu 18.04 already include imagemagick executable from default install, since when I type convert -version it show
Version ImageMagick 6.9.7-4

so I create a simple php page

```
<?php
  $im = new imagick();
?>
```

but when I load this page on the browser I get the following error message.

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'imagick' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/index.php:2 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/index.php on line 2

so I search the website, it mention that I  need to install php-imagick, so I type in
   sudo apt-get install php-imagick
The installation seems to be ok and it also seems to configure the correct php version which is 7.2.5 
Then I restart apache server from xampp contol panel

then I reload the page again, I still have the same issue/error message

am I missing steps to get imagick working on php?

Thank you.

Regards
- Haris -

Answer (score 0):

Did you configre you php.ini to include imagick.so? find the php.ini files thats used and add extension=imagick.so to the end or in your extensions section